# Sharepoint 2007 ignoring IIS MIME types

Tags: sharepoint, iis, mime-types, httpresponse

I have two WebSites configured in my IIS 6.0. The first one is a normal WebSite and the other is a Sharepoint Web Application.

In order to setup the MIME type for .mp4 files, I went to both WebSites properties and under HTTP Header I clicked on "MIME Types..." button and entered:

```
Extension: .mp4
MIME Type: video/mp4
```

It works fine for the normal WebSite. But the Sharepoint WebSite seems to ignore this configuration (the HTTP response header content-type field is missing).

Is there a way to configure a Sharepoint Web Application to understand different content-types?

Answer (score -1):

Please verify below settings(for SP2010).

1. Open Central Administration Site.
2. On left hand menu, click on Application Management.
3. In “Web Applications” section, Click on “Manage web applications” link.
4. Select the desired application by clicking on it.
5. Now on the Ribbon menu (Top Menu), Click on General Settings Icon arrow. A pop up will open, in this pop up select General Settings.
6. Another pop up page will open, scroll down the page and go to “Browser File Handling” section.
7. In my case by default it was set to strict. I change this setting to Permissive.
8. Click OK and it was done.

If it solves your issues, have a look at detailed description [here](http://dhondiyals.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/resolved-run-swf-and-other-mime-type-files-in-web-browser-in-sharepoint-2010-scnerio/)

Comment: I don't see this this Browser File Handling in SharePoint 2007 Central Admin.  How do you do this in 2007?